# How is the size calculated of the area near a hydrogen atom that a photon must hit to ionize the atom?

Tags: photons, hydrogen

I do not know of any specific other information needed to answer the question.

Comment: https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Ionization/intro.html

Comment: When asking a question like this, you are likely to get a better answer if you mention what level of quantum mechanics you understand.

Comment: My understanding of QM is minimal. Most of what I have read is conceptual rather than mathematical.

Comment: My level of QK knowledge is marginal. The books I have read on the topic have only a little math. I found a statement in the article you cited which confuses me. "The theory used in this ionization cross section database is specifically designed for electron-impact ionization." What does "electron-impact" mean? It might mean an electron is the particle that hits another electron, or it might mean that a photon hits an electron.

Comment: Electron-impact means that an incoming electron causes the atom to ionize. In QM there are no classical trajectories so (despite the word “impact”) the incoming electron can’t be imagined as actually hitting an electron in the atom. The EM interactions between the incoming electron and the atomic electrons can result in ionization.

Comment: I’m sorry, I just realized that you are asking about ionization by photons. My apologies. Forget the link I provided. The general statements I made about trajectories are still valid.

Comment: I think [this page](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantum/node90.html) calculates the photo-ionization cross-section that you are asking about.

Comment: Thank you G. Smith.

Comment: Thank you again G. Smith.  This is exactly what I was hoping to learn.

Answer (score 2):

[This lesson](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantum/node90.html) from Richard Fitzpatrick’s *Quantum Mechanics* [course](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantum/Quantumhtml.html) calculates the [cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)) for a hydrogen atom in its ground state to be ionized by an incoming photon. The result (eq. 8.259) is

$$\sigma\approx\frac{256\pi}{3}\alpha\left(\frac{I}{\hbar\omega}\right)^{7/2}\left(1-\frac{I}{\hbar\omega}\right)^{3/2}a_0^2 $$

where $a_0$ is the [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius), $\alpha$ is the [fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant), $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant, $\omega$ is the angular frequency of the photon, and $I=\hbar^2/(2m_ea_0^2)$ is the ionization energy of the ground state of hydrogen. (In that last formula, $m_e$ is the mass of the electron.)

This formula is valid when the photon’s energy is much greater than the ionization energy ($\hbar\omega\gg I$) and the ionized electron is non-relativistic. (The linked page has references to more complicated calculations when these constraints don’t apply.)

In this regime, the cross section is much smaller than the size of the atom. For example, when the photon has 100 times the ionization energy ($\hbar\omega/I=100$), $\sigma=1.9\times 10^{-7}a_0^2$. This is about $5.4\times 10^{-28}\text{ m}^2.$

The calculation of the cross-section involves applying [time-dependent perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) to the [hydrogen ground state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) found by solving the Schrodinger equation for hydrogen. The initial ground state gets perturbed by the time-varying electromagnetic field of the photon, and there is some probability that the final state of the atom is an ionized state.